# Attribute routing based on the existence of a querystring parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I would like two different methods to be called depending on whether the request is `GET /things/123` or `GET /things/123?preview`

Obviously, this would be a workaround:

```
[RoputePrefix("api/things")]
...
[HttpGet, Route("{id}")]
public object GetThing(int id)
{
    if (Request.RequestUri.Query == "?preview")
        return GetPreview(id);
    else
        return GetFull(id);
}
```

...at which point it's almost like using `bool preview = false` as a parameter and adding `?preview=true` to the request. But I want this syntax instead and would prefer to handle it with routing if possible.

For reasons not shown here, I can't do the next easiest thing, which is to use `/preview` as a suffix.

Comment: You could do something like this: [HttpGet, Route("{id}/preview")]
public object GetThing2(int id)
It would be GET /things/123/preview, which isn't exactly what you had stated, but probably achieves the same result.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment that adds a path segment, not a querystring.

Comment: correct, its not clear from your question what you are hoping to achieve. you could do Route("{id}/{param}") public object GetThing(int id, string param) as well, but it is hard to determine from the question what your real goal is. Preview seems like a static value, not a query parameter.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment what isn't clear? I just want to add that flag. The reason why I can't use `/preview` is that `id` is actually a path and contains slashes. I didn't add that to avoid making the question more complicated.